# Null Pointer Exception when accessing Google Analytics report data using different credentials

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

I am following the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api) to get access to the GA account report data by executing a simple GA query, by using the Google Developers console. 
I followed all steps mentioned in the tutorial and the code works fine.

I have included the code below.

```
public class GoogleAnalyticsAccess {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "GAAccess/1.0";
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/analytics_sample");
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;
    private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

    public static Credential authorizeUser() throws IOException {

        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(
                GoogleAnalyticsAccess.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));
        if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter") ||
            clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
            System.out.println("Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=analytics " +
                               "into Dashboard/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY,
                                                                                   clientSecrets, Collections.singleton(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY))
                .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory).build();

        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    }

    public static Analytics getAnalyticsServiceObject(Credential credential){

        return new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                                                                             .build();
    }

    public static String getGAAccountId(Analytics analytics) throws IOException {

        String accountId =null;

        Accounts accounts = analytics.management().accounts().list().execute();
        List<Account> accountsList = accounts.getItems();

        if(accountsList.isEmpty()){
            System.err.println("No accounts found");
        }
        else{

            for(int i=0; i<accountsList.size();i++){
                if(accountsList.get(i).getName().equals("XXXX")){
                    accountId = accountsList.get(i).getId();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return accountId;
    }

    public static String getGAWebPropertyId(Analytics analytics,String accountId) throws IOException {

        String webPropertyId = null;

        Webproperties webProperties = null;

        webProperties = analytics.management().webproperties().list(accountId).execute();
        List<Webproperty> webPropertiesList = webProperties.getItems();

        if (webPropertiesList.isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("No Web Properties found");
        } else {

            for (int i=0; i<webPropertiesList.size();i++){
                if(webPropertiesList.get(i).getName().equals("XXXX")){
                    webPropertyId = webPropertiesList.get(i).getId();
                }
            }
        }

        return webPropertyId;
    }

    public static String getGAViewId(Analytics analytics, String accountId, String webPropertyId) throws IOException {

        String viewId = null;

        Profiles views = analytics.management().profiles().list(accountId, webPropertyId).execute();
        List<Profile> viewsList = views.getItems();

        if (viewsList.isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("No profiles found");
        } else {
            for(int i=0; i<viewsList.size();i++){
                if(viewsList.get(i).getName().equals("XXXX")){
                    viewId = viewsList.get(i).getId();
                }
            }
        }

        return viewId;

    }

    public static List<GoogleAnalyticsData> executeGAQuery(Analytics analytics, String viewId, String dimension) throws IOException {

        List<GoogleAnalyticsData> dataList = new ArrayList<GoogleAnalyticsData>();

        if (viewId == null) {
            System.err.println("No profiles found.");
        } else {
            GaData gaData = analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + viewId, "2015-02-13", "2015-02-27", "ga:users")
                                     .setDimensions("ga:" + dimension)
                                     .setMaxResults(200).execute();

            if (gaData.getRows() == null || gaData.getRows().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No results Found.");
            } else {
                GoogleAnalyticsData data;
                for (List<String> row : gaData.getRows()) {
                    data = new GoogleAnalyticsData();
                    data.setName(row.get(0));
                    data.setValue(Integer.parseInt(row.get(1)));

                    dataList.add(data);
                }
            }
        }

        return dataList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);

        Credential credential = authorizeUser();
        Analytics analytics = getAnalyticsServiceObject(credential);
        String accountId = getGAAccountId(analytics);
        String webPropertyId = getGAWebPropertyId(analytics,accountId);
        String viewId = getGAViewId(analytics,accountId,webPropertyId);

        List<GoogleAnalyticsData> continentDataList = executeGAQuery(analytics, viewId, "continent");
        List<GoogleAnalyticsData> countryDataList = executeGAQuery(analytics, viewId, "country");

        for(int i =0; i <continentDataList.size();i++){
            System.out.println(continentDataList.get(i).getName() + " " + continentDataList.get(i).getValue());

        }

        for(int i=0; i< countryDataList.size();i++){
            System.out.println(countryDataList.get(i).getName() + " " + countryDataList.get(i).getValue());
        }

    }

}
```

I get an error when I access the same GA account report data by giving the credential (Client secret and Id) of another user who also has shared access to that report data.
I am successfully able to access the report data using the other users credentials If I have already run the java application using my credentials first. But If I run the app with the other users credentials first, then I get the following error.

The Stack trace is shown below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:92)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at org.dashboard.access.data.GoogleAnalyticsAccess.getGAAccountId(GoogleAnalyticsAccess.java:266)
at org.dashboard.access.data.GoogleAnalyticsAccess.main(GoogleAnalyticsAccess.java:364)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

The specific exception occurs at the following line in method getGAAccountId.

```
Accounts accounts = analytics.management().accounts().list().execute();
```

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Client id and secret wont give you access to a google analytics account.  its a access token and refresh token.  Posting the stack trace with out the code that you are using isn't going to help anyone debug your code.

Comment: the bug was marked as fixed on December 29, 2014, and its been closed so I would have to assume it is fixed and is not your problem.  That tutorial is from 2012 and is probably out of date for the newer client library.

Comment: @DaImTo : In order to validate the user, before obtaining the access and refresh tokens, we need the client secret and id and also there is no updated documentation for the google apis. It would be helpful If you could point me to some.

Comment: You only need one client id and client secret for your application you should not be changing it.  You can have an unlimited number of users for a single client id and client secret so I don't understand why you are changing it if you have it working with one.

Comment: Unfortunatly my Java knowledge is very limited.   I suspect your issue is not understanding how client ids work.   But to be sure I have sent an email to the Google Devs in charge of that tutorial to get some info from them that the tutorial does work, and its not out of date.   Lets see if they respond.

Comment: I am developing this application using the credentials from my gmail account, but the application will be used with the credentials of another user. That's why I am searching for the possibility of changing the credentials and accessing the api.
Okay. Thank you very much.

Comment: credentials come from https://console.developers.google.com and have nothing to do with your gmail account or your users gmail account.  I think you might want to read about Oauth2

Comment: In order to get access to the developer console we need to have gmail accounts, therefore the projects we created in the developer console separately has different credentials. I will check OAuth2. Thank you.

Comment: Does the user that gets the NullPointerException have a Google Analytics account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your client_secrets.json is well configured, you just have to delete the file .store/analytics_sample and run it again.

Comment: That was exactly the issue. Deleting it and running the app fixed it. After running the app I had to authenticate by logging into the other users gmail account. Thats all. Thank you very much..